# Shell from a Firefox tab

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, firefox

I have a requirement for a user in the office where they would like to open a terminal shell within a Firefox tab.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 3):

Set up an SSH server on their machines and install the [FireSSH](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firessh/) addon.