# How can I use a terminal within a Firefox tab?

Tags: ssh, firefox, vnc, gnome-terminator

I love the [Tree Style Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/) extension for organizing tabs in Firefox. In fact, I would like to use it to organize my open terminal windows too! I don't want to launch a terminal window from within Firefox or launch Firefox from a terminal. I want to be able to view and type in a terminal in a Firefox tab, *as if it were a web page*. I'm running Ubuntu 20.40.

**Idea 1 - an embedded app**: I searched for Firefox extensions which allow running a terminal or application in Firefox--perhaps conceptually like Microsoft's [Object Linking and Embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding)--but came up empty.

**Idea 2 - VNC**: With noVNC (`sudo snap install novnc` and `novnc --listen 6081 --vnc localhost:5901`) and x11vnc (`sudo apt install -y x11vnc` and `xwininfo` to get the window ID and `x11vnc -rfbport 5901 -id 0x4000007 -viewonly`), I can view the given window within Firefox. However, running the above without `-viewonly` makes the mouse jump from Firefox to the real terminal window whenever I try to type in the terminal within Firefox. This might be solved by launching the real terminal in a dummy display which has its own mouse pointer, but I don't know how to do that. (I'm currently using X11, but would very much appreciate a solution that works on Wayland too.)

**Idea 3 - ssh client**: Another approach is a web-based ssh client or ssh Firefox extension. [SSHGate](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sshgate-ssh-client-terminal/) might work, but it only has 2 stars and hasn't been updated for 5 years. Also, [Shell from a Firefox tab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39535/shell-from-a-firefox-tab) suggests [FireSSH](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firessh/), but it is no longer available.

What approach would you suggest for running a terminal within a Firefox tab on Ubuntu?

Comment: Check out [WeTTY](https://github.com/butlerx/wetty). No creepy Firefox extensions or VNC desktops are needed.

Comment: You could also run a local webserver with [`shellinabox`](https://github.com/shellinabox/shellinabox).

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the [Onion library](https://coralbits.com/static/onion/) has (as a demo) a terminal running inside a web browser. It is the [oterm](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion/tree/master/examples/oterm) example.

[onion](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion) is a library, coded mostly in C, that add web serving capabilities to your program.

Comment: Thanks. It was pretty simple to build and test oterm, and it looks fast and clean. However, I could not find a way to paste text into the terminal, and it appears to not support Unicode characters. I need both of these.

Comment: Onion has  a mailing list. You could ask there.